# Yii2 uploaded audio file not getting save in upload folder

Tags: file, audio, upload, yii2

I have a form that have file upload option for both image and audio file. The image file are getting save but not the audio file although the path get save in database.
The form model:

```
public $file;
public $binary_file;
public $s_date, $e_date;
public $comment;

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'complain';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['complain'], 'required'],
        [['complain'], 'string'],
        [['file'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
        [['binary_file'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'mp3'],
        [['s_date','e_date','complain_date', 'last_updated'], 'safe'],
        [['comment'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['complain_no'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
    ];
}
```

And the model in which the file will be actually save:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['complain_item_id', 'complain_id'], 'required'],
        [['complain_item_id', 'complain_id'], 'integer'],
        [['file'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
    ];
}
```

the form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]);   ?>

    <div class='col-md-12'>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'complain')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($model->isNewRecord) {?> 
        <div class='col-md-4'>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'file[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true])->label('Upload Image') ?>
        </div>

        <div class='col-md-4'>
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'binary_file')->fileInput()->label('Upload Mp3') ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="form-group" style='padding-left:14px;'>
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Submit' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-info submit' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

An the controller code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Complain();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->save(false);

        // save the image path to database and save the image to the upload folder

        if($model->file = UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'file')) {
            $path = 'uploads/img';
            FileHelper::createDirectory($path);

            foreach($model->file as $fil) {   
                $modelsComplain= new ComplainItem();

                $modelsComplain->save(false);
                $fil->saveAs('uploads/img/img'. $fil->extension);

                $modelsComplain->file = 'img/img'. $fil->extension;
                $modelsComplain->update(false);
            }
        }

        if($model->binary_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'binary_file')) {

            $path = 'uploads/mp3';
            FileHelper::createDirectory($path);

            $modelsComplain= new ComplainItem();

            $modelsComplain->save(false);

            $model->binary_file->saveAs('uploads/mp3/mp3'. $model->binary_file->extension);

            $modelsComplain->file ='mp3/mp3'. $model->binary_file->extension; 
            $modelsComplain->update(false); 
        } 

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->complain_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use move_uploaded_file

```
if(isset($_FILES['binary_file']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['binary_file']['tmp_name'] != null)
{
    $image = $_FILES['binary_file'];

    $file = $_FILES;

    $new_image['name'] = $_FILES['binary_file']['name'];
    $new_image['type'] = $_FILES['binary_file']['type'];
    $new_image['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['binary_file']['tmp_name'];
    $new_image['error'] = $_FILES['binary_file']['error'];
    $new_image['size'] = $_FILES['binary_file']['size'];
    $image = $new_image;

    $model->binary_file = Yii::$app->params['upload_folder'].time().$file['binary_file']['name']; //set your path
    /**
    * for uploding image as it is in folder
    */
    move_uploaded_file($file['binary_file']['tmp_name'],Yii::getAlias('@webroot')."/".$model->binary_file);

}
```